# Issues with ARP I think? And bridged interface

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall

I work with a large school district network. We are having issues with our content filter associating all IP addresses to the same MAC address (the gateway MAC address). I have the content filter in between the gateway and the firewall and the content filter is using two interfaces in bridged mode. This is so we catch all traffic headed to the internet. Everything seems to be functioning, except that all device MACs are showing as the same in the content filter. The content filter vendor says it is something with the way the VLAN is terminated? I have no doubt it is some configuration I need to make to allow the device to see the MAC address in the ARP packet header. We are using Juniper switches, Linewize content filter, and Watchguard firewall. I am mostly self taught and can't seem to figure out how I would get this to work.

Comment: After some more googling, i think i might need to set the ip address of the bridged interface to one within the local network rather than leaving it blank or setting a random address. From what i understand (correct me if i am wrong) it cant see the macs because the interface is in a different network than the interface (on the router) it is connected to.

Comment: Anything called a gateway is at least a router, which means it separates subnets. Ethernet MAC addresses are an Ethernet-layer concept that don't traverse routers. So it makes sense that your content filter sees all those IP addresses as coming via the MAC address of the upstream side of the gateway/router.

Comment: The IP addresses being different is not the _cause_ – it's an _effect_ of the physical topology (i.e. what the interfaces are connected to).

Comment: I'm starting to realize that your Question as currently written doesn't really make clear what problem you're trying to solve. Is it somehow a problem that the content filter doesn't see the MAC addresses of the devices on the other side of the gateway? You might want to either edit this Question to make it more clear what problem you're trying to solve. It would also help if you explained what subnets are where. I'm guessing you have two subnets, one on either side of the "gateway"?

Comment: It is a problem, our content filter was originally put there to catch byod traffic without the need for app installation. When they connect to wifi it redirects them to a captive portal to sign into the content filter so that they can access the internet. It associates this device ip and mac address to the user. With it seeing the same mac for every ip address, it thinks it is the same user logging in on every byod device.

Comment: I will add that we use a managed WAN and the same company that does our managed wan is our isp. It is routed a bit weird in that they have the firewall connected to their device in between our buildings and the firewall and we are actually using the same connection we have routed to them for WAN and isp. I may need to get with them to figure out the best way to proceed.